# SQL - выбрать из строки до последнего вхождения

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `Info`, где храняться пути, например:

> /mnt/sd/DATA/LINUX/DATA_2/lin/ToR/Transit/Transit_ILE00-wwwwww1749.txt

или

> /mnt/ssd/DATA/LINUX/DATA_2/lin/ToR/Transit/1/2/Transit_ILE00-MSsdsdsdwww.txt

Как выбрать только до последнего вхождения `'/'`, чтобы получилось:

> /mnt/sd/DATA/LINUX/DATA_2/lin/ToR/Transit/

и

> /mnt/ssd/DATA/LINUX/DATA_2/lin/ToR/Transit/1/2/

С `REGEXP_REPLACE` и `SUBSTRING_INDEX` у меня не получается.

Comment: Вы приведите пример решения, желательно со ссылкой на SQLFiddle

Comment: Я пробовал так, но здесь задаются фиксированные параметры вхождений шаблона.
select SUBSTRING_INDEX (SUBSTRING_INDEX(Info, '/', 5),'/', -5) as path from table1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT LEFT(`field`, LENGTH(`field`) - INSTR(REVERSE(`field`),'/'))
FROM `Info`
```

**UPDATE:**

Запрос был написан в предположении, что "до последнего вхождения" означает "невключительно". Но в примере последний слэш включён в ответ - значит:

```
SELECT LEFT(`field`, LENGTH(`field`) - INSTR(REVERSE(`field`),'/') + 1)
FROM `Info`
```

Comment: Черт пишет что не найдена функция STR_REVERSE
SELECT LEFT(`Info`, LENGTH(`Info`) - INSTR(STR_REVERSE(`Info`),'/')) FROM `transit_history`

Comment: Опечатка, она просто REVERSE(). Поправил.

Answer (score 6):

Всё как и в обычном программировании: находим последний слэш и обрезаем до него. Для этого используем следующие функции:

- **`LOCATE(subset, str)`** – находит первую встречу подстроки в строке ([документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)).
- **`REVERSE(str)`** – переставляет символы строки в обратной последовательности ([документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse)). Это нужно чтобы искать последний слэш в строке.
- **`LENGTH(str)`** – возвращает длину строки ([документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length)). Это нужно потому, что мы получаем индекс последнего слэша с конца строки, а нам нужно от её начала.
- **`LEFT(str, len)`** – вырезает левую часть строки по заданной длине ([документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left)).

Получается такой код:

```
SELECT LEFT(path_field , LENGTH(path_field) - LOCATE('/', REVERSE(path_field) + 1)
FROM sometable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT reverse(substr(reverse('fieldName'), instr(reverse('fieldName'),'/')))
FROM 'tableName'
```

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь!

Comment: 1) Автору требуется разделитель слэш. 2) Вероятно, неправильно работает, если разделитель отсутствует - возвращает пустую строку.

Comment: 1) Прошу простить за невнимательность! Исправил '-' на '/'. 2) Код работает, проверял